# PostgreSql 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu, pdo

pdo is working fine with mysql but with pgsql its giving error `'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'` I've installed `php5-pgsql` package which also includes `pdo_pgsql`

http://packages.debian.org/sid/php5-pgsql

> This package provides a module for PostgreSQL database connections directly from PHP scripts. It also includes the pdo_pgsql module for use with the PHP Data Object extension.

my dsn is `pgsql:dbname=DB;host=192.168.0.2`
I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Sorry I was checking the wrong server. Its Gentoo and here postgresql is not installed.

Comment: I'd request the moderetors to please delete the question if possible

Comment: on your own questions, you can delete them by yourself by clicking on the appropriate link at the bottom of your question

Comment: I've got this error as well. My issue is I was connecting through a DSN using a format similar to Heroku's: while it says "postgre:", the correct driver for PDO is "pgsql:"

Comment: Check my [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53661888/5279996) in another similar publication. GL

Answer (score 61):

This message means you need to **install** and or **activate** postgresql extension in PHP

This solution works for me :
**To install postgresql** extension

```
[sudo] apt-get install php-pgsql
```

after, **for activating it**, uncomment `pgsql` and `pdo-pgsql` extensions in `etc/php/$PHP_VERSION/apache2/php.ini` file

[image]

Finally, type :

```
[sudo] /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

To restart apache server if you use apache such as was my case...

Comment: It is worth noting in my initial install of php, there were 2 php.ini files. Not knowing what one to uncomment, I did them both.

Answer (score 22):

1) Have you enabled pgsql.so in `php.ini` (`extension=pgsql.so`)?

2) Is you Postgresql listenin on `192.168.0.2` interface? (You can check it by `netstat -tpln`)

3) How you authenticate your access into Postgresql?

Comment: I had to do `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service` before it worked.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you've uncommented the line that tells php where the Postgres driver is (usually `extension=pgsql.so`) in the main `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  First of all - check is it enabled in php.ini.  Uncomment `extension=php_pdo_pgsql...`

than set up extension directory!!

```
extension_dir = "ext" ; for your case it could be other dir.
```

and do not forget to restart server after changing the config.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove semicolon in front of

> extension=pgsql
>   extension=pgsql.so

included in your *php.ini* file

You can do that from the XAMPP Control Panel.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to solve the problem.

1. Edit `php.ini` and remove `;` from `extension=pdo_pgsql`. Also, add `extension=pgsql.so` to the `php.ini` file.
2. Make sure to restart the Apache server before you try to see the result.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with another solution. I lost my around 4 hours to solve this problem. Please check the following to solve this problem.

1. Check `php.ini` file and remove semicolon from this line

   `extension=pgsql`

   `extension=pdo_pgsql`
2. Restart your apache2 server

   `sudo service apache2 restart`
3. Check if your PDO driver has updated in localhost `phpinfo()`

[image]

I did All the things right and still I had this problem. And you know why? Because I had several versions of php installed. So I was running `php7.4` in my php cli but localhost was running on `php7.2`. So always check your php versions.

4. Check your php version on localhost and terminal cli

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you do not have postgresql installed on the same machine that is Apache and PHP; you have to install `php-pgsql` and **don't have to add extensions** in `php.ini` manually in Linux ([in Windows yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53661888/5279996)), because redundancies are generated and this does not work (checked in `error.log`).

```
$ sudo apt install php-pgsql
```

Then you can check the existence of the extension enabled automatically in:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
```

*Observations*: In `phpinfo()` you will find the directory `conf.d/` and the file `error.log`

GL

Answer (score 1):

Just run php --ini and look for Loaded Configuration File in output for the location of php.ini used by your CLI

then check you have enabled the extensions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

using Amazon ec2 linux 2 (redhat ?);
PHP from Apache would not find driver but it was there on command line (psql)
After spending an inordinate amount of time checking config files, out of desperation, I rebooted the ec2 server instance- and problem solved (just like windows :) as dogbert tech support once said "shut up and reboot"

Answer (score -4):

**Copy libpq.dll from the PHP directory to Apache24\bin** (or wherever your installation could be).