# How do I enable php to work with postgresql?

Tags: php, windows, postgresql, pdo

```
<?php

try {
   $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=###;user=###;password=##');
   echo "PDO connection object created";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
      echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I get the error message "Could Not Load Driver"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7240866/705198 Covers this issue on debian linux derivatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install pdo for postgres Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180869/install-pdo-for-postgres-ubuntu)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this:

Uncomment the following in php.ini by removing the ";"

```
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Use the following code to connect to a postgresql database server:

```
pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=username password=password")
    or die("Can't connect to database".pg_last_error());
```

Comment: I'm still seeing `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect()`, although I *know* I've uncommented it. Ideas?

Comment: Related to Postgres I had the line `extension=pdo_pgsql`, after uncommenting the error was solved

Answer (score 91):

You need to install the pgsql module for php.
In debian/ubuntu is something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Or if the package is installed, you need to enable de module in php.ini

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll (windows)
extension=php_pgsql.so (linux)
```

Greatings.

Comment: Hi do you know how I would install it in windows? Sorry I don't have ubuntu yet..

Comment: Depends. You are using wamp or something like that?

Comment: try to enable the module first, editing php.ini and searching for php_pgsql and remove the ; in the begining of the line. Then you need to reload your service.

Comment: Just an update on this old thread for php7 the command is: sudo apt install php7.0-pgsql

Comment: Running php 7.0 - I had to add "extension=pgsql.so" to "php.ini"  = "open database successfully" = :)

Comment: Generally, the command is sudo apt-get install phpVersion-pgsql

Answer (score 16):

For debian/ubuntu install

```
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
```

Answer (score 8):

- SO: Windows/Linux
- HTTP Web Server: Apache
- Programming language: PHP

### Enable PHP to work with PostgreSQL in Apache

In Apache I edit the following configuration file: `C:\xampp\php.ini`

I make sure to have the following lines uncommented:

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll 
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

**Finally restart Apache before attempting a new connection to the database engine.**

---

Also, I leave my code that ensures that the connection is unique:

```
private static $pdo = null;

public static function provideDataBaseInstance() {
    if (self::$pdo == null) {
        $dsn = "pgsql:host=" . HOST .
               ";port=5432;dbname=" . DATABASE .
               ";user=" . POSTGRESQL_USER .
               ";password=" . POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD;
        try {
            self::$pdo = new PDO($dsn);
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            $msg = $exception->getMessage();
            echo $msg . 
                 ". Do not forget to enable in the web server the database 
                  manager for php and in the database instance authorize the 
                  ip of the server instance if they not in the same 
                  instance.";
        }
    }
    return self::$pdo;
}
```

GL

Answer (score 6):

I have to add in httpd.conf this line (Windows):

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/8.3/bin/libpq.dll"
```

Comment: Where would one find httpd.conf

Comment: inside config file for your apache server. If you are using mamp, then C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Answer (score 3):

just install the database driver:

> apt-get install php5-pgsql php5-mysql php5-sqlite ... and so on ...

and be happy!

Comment: And reload the PHP config (reload apache/nginx etc) after install new extensions

Answer (score 3):

I installed PHP on windows IIS using Windows Platform Installer (WPΙ). WPΙ creates a "PHP Manager" tool in "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" console. I am configuring PHP using this tool.

in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php says:

*PDO and all the major drivers ship with PHP as shared extensions, and simply need to be activated by editing the php.ini file:
extension=php_pdo.dll*

so i activated the extension using PHP Manager and now PDO works fine

PHP manager simple added the following two lines in my php.ini, you can add the lines by hand. Of course you must restart the web server.

```
[PHP_PDO_PGSQL]
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: I do installed PHP via WPI, and it was enough for me to add extension=php_pgsql.dll to C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\php.ini at the end of the [ExtensionList] section

Answer (score 1):

You need to isntall pdo_pgsql package

Comment: How do I install that package on windows?

Comment: Maybe `pecl install pdo_pgsql`. Not sure

Answer (score 1):

I and many other shave spent way too long on this - this needs a massive improvement.  After spending hours, I finally copied php_pgsql.dll from php's ext directory to Apache24's root directory (wherever you installed it) and finally Apache was able to get the php/pg modules and dlls loaded.

Comment: Awesome thanks, if I were using xammp would I put this in the C:\xampp folder?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=###;user=###;password=##');
```

For PDO type connection uncomment

`extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` and comment with

`;extension=php_pgsql.dll`

```
$dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=### user=### password=####");
```

For pgconnect type connection comment

`;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` and uncomment

`extension=php_pgsql.dll`

Both the connections should work.

Answer (score 1):

Because some answers seem outdated, if you are working with xampp, go to the `php` folder inside your xampp installation. In it open the `php.ini` file and uncomment

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

Remove the `;` before these lines.

Answer (score 0):

in my case there are **2 php.ini**, I had to uncomment extension pdo_pgsql in both php.ini

1. in **php** folder
2. in **apache** folder

both inside in **wamp** folder

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AppServ on Windows, then:

**To Enable PHP to work with PostgreSQL in Apache**

1. Go to `C:\AppServ\php7\php.ini`.
2. Uncomment this line: `;extension=pgsql` removing the `;`.