# PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: postgresql, php-pgsql

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /home/kholifah/htdocs/cechcalk.ck/userAuth.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /home/kholifah/htdocs/cechcalk.ck/userAuth.php(22): PDO->__construct('?????pgsql:dbna...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/kholifah/htdocs/cechcalk.ck/userAuth.php on line 22

Comment: Check my [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53661888/5279996) in another similar publication. GL

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing module called pdo_pgsql.

Look in your php.ini for a line `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`. It should be uncommented.

On Ubuntu or other linux distribution you can install PDO driver with something like 
`apt-get install php5-pgsql`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem into xampp now its works for me, May be it will helpful to you also in linux platform lamp or latest version of Php 5.6 - 7.

Just uncomment these lines from php.ini file

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

Example from my php.ini file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The earliest answers forgot to mention that you need to restart some services after enabling the following in `php.ini` file:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

You need to restart your web server, in my case my using `nginx`, so I do

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

After that I restart `php-fpm` using:

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Thats All...cheers