# PropelException in Symfony. Using PHP and XAMPP

Tags: php, symfony, xampp

I got the following error:

> [wrapped: pgsql extension not loaded [User Info: Array]]

I am using PHP 5.4, the latest Symfony and XAMPP. Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: you got this message in Symfony2 logs? give more info

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable php to work with postgresql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640821/how-do-i-enable-php-to-work-with-postgresql)

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen i copied the answer in the given link but there's this error **Call to undefined function pg_connect()**

Comment: Did you [enable the extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640821/how-do-i-enable-php-to-work-with-postgresql)?