# postgres pg_dump not working

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I have a VPS running centos 7 in which I have installed Postgresql-9.3. It was running fine for the last one year. Now, when I need to take a backup using pg_dump it is not working. It was working. I used

```
pg_dump -d <role_name> > <backup_file_name.sql>
```

It doesn't show any errors. But there is no backup file being created.
SQL Queries are working fine.

Also my project (based on Yii framework) is unable to connect with the database anymore. Shows

> ```
> CDbException
>
> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver
> ```

It all suddenly happened and I am stuck.

None of the logs give me any hint. Where should I check to find out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As for second question - seems like you are missing php-postgress drivers, exactly as error message says. You can try installing them back, as described in this question: [How do I enable php to work with postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640821/how-do-i-enable-php-to-work-with-postgresql)

As for the first - I think that you updated or removed some important packages from your system. Also it could be upgrade consequences.