# I can't run php artisan migrate in my project

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration, laragon

I installed laragon 5.0, and enable postgresql 14, but however, when i run the command "php artisan migrate", i'm getting this error:

```
  Dropping all tables .............................................................................................................. 12ms FAIL  

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select tablename, concat('"', schemaname, '"."', tablename, '"') as qualifiedname from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname in ('public'))

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:801
    797▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    798▕                 );
    799▕             }
    800▕
  ➜ 801▕             throw new QueryException(
    802▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    803▕             );
    804▕         }
    805▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname='sistema_ordenes_servicio';port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "postgres", Object(SensitiveParameterValue), [])
```

I will be very grateful for any help!

i try explain my trouble and solve it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085039/postgresql-pdoexception-with-message-could-not-find-driver ?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the PostgreSQL driver is not installed or configured properly in your Laravel environment. Make sure you have the PostgreSQL driver installed and enabled in your PHP configuration. You may need to install the `pdo_pgsql` extension.